# JavaMail IMAP throws exceptions with NULL message

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

I am using JavaMail IMAP protocol to process emails from gmail. While processing emails, javamail gives NULL exception message and the following stack trace:

> DEBUG com.iot.std.listener.EmailListener - null
>   com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getProtocol(IMAPMessage.java:169)
>   com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadBODYSTRUCTURE(IMAPMessage.java:1546)
>   com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getDataHandler(IMAPMessage.java:808)
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent(MimeMessage.java:1502)

This stops my email listener with an unexpected exception, but since the message is NULL I don't know what exception it is. 
This happens for more than 600 mails at usually at the end of the message array.
This is my store connection and folder opening code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
props.put("mail.imap.host", host);
props.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
props.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class",
        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993");


Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect(host, 
ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationBaseUrl().getAppianEmailMonitorUsername(), 
ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationBaseUrl().getAppianEmailMonitorPassword());

String folderToMonitor = "INBOX";
Folder folder = store.getFolder(folderToMonitor);
 folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
 Message[] msgs = folder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
```

Comment: Print the *exception*, not only its message. It is the message that is null, not the exception.

Comment: Just added one line on top of stack trace, this is all that I am getting.

Comment: The exception stacktrace shows MimeMessage#getContent, the issue is probably occurring when reading a message

Comment: I don't believe you've posted the exception at all, *or* the entire stack trace.

Comment: My guess is that you get a `FolderClosedException`, see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/javax.mail/com.springsource.javax.mail/1.4.5/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPMessage.java#IMAPMessage.getProtocol%28%29 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550624/folderclosed-exception-in-javamail (similar stack)

Comment: I'm not prepared to engage in guesswork. If you can't provide a proper exception and stack trace you're off-topic.

Comment: While you're fixing things, [get rid of the socket factory settings](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  Also, what version of JavaMail are you using?  Get the [latest version](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) if possible.  And include the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) in your post.